# How do I get userID for Appwrite Magic URL authentication?

Tags: javascript, authentication, appwrite

Since userIDs are unique and not the user's email, I don't know their ID until I login.

How do I get userID for the user to authenticate using magicURL to log in?

```
const promise = account.createMagicURLSession('WHAT DO I PUT HERE????', 'email@example.com');
```

Thanks

I was expecting to log in with just the email?

Comment: I'm sorry, You're a developer advocate at appwrite (per your bio) and yet you ask how to use it? This looks like spam to me 

Comment:  I genuinely have no clue why this is implemented this way

Comment: Cool story but your's and the person who wrote the answer history suggests otherwise

Answer (score 0):

The `account.createMagicURLSession()` endpoint will create a user if no user has a matching email. This is the only time the `userId` parameter will be used. Otherwise, if a user with a matching email already exists, the `userId` parameter is ignored.

The typical scenario is to put `ID.unique()` for the `userId` so that a unique ID will be used if a user needs to be created. Otherwise, you can generate a custom ID (maybe something derived from the email) or any other custom ID you want, but it must be unique.

Comment: Why can't we just leave user ID empty if it's ignored anyway, or make it optional?

Comment: On the API side, if it's left optional, then the API would have to respond with an error if an account needs to be created but a user ID was not supplied. This is dangerous because it could allow a bad actor to discover the existence of users (If I make an API call `account.createMagicURLSession()` and get an error back, the user doesn't exist. However, if I don't get an error back, the user does exist).

Comment: A developer making an app also can't leave user ID blank/empty unless they for sure know the user doesn't exist. They could do this by having a separate log in vs sign up page and rely on the user to use the correct one.